# matchbox-keyboard grabs the upper half of the screen

Tags: debian, raspbian, openbox

When I run `matchbox-keyboard`, all maximized windows become resized to occupy only the lower half of the screen, while custom-sized windows stay intact. In the screenshot below, Chromium got resized, but not the terminal:

[image]

When I close the on-screen keyboard, the maximized windows get back to their almost-fullscreen size.

I also installed `matchbox-keyboard` on a vanilla Debian x86, where it behaves even weirder: maximized apps are still restricted to the lower part of the screen, but the keyboard also takes the lower part, leaving the upper part of the screen empty:

[image]

How exactly is this feature implemented, and is it configurable? Is it possible to start a different application (e.g. `leafpad`) in this mode, or run `matchbox-keyboard` so that it would occupy the lower part of the screen and let the maximized apps take the upper part?

Comment: As this is specific to RasPi, I'd suggest deleting the question here and asking it in the [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) -community instead.

Comment: @Peregrino69 What makes you think it is specific to the Pi? I assume it's a feature of Openbox, or linux accessibility / assistive technology, or perhaps Xlib.

Comment: @Peregrino69 `matchbox-keyboard` was written in 2004 according to its man page, so it predates the Pi by 8 years or so and certanly wasn't written for it. It also behaves similarly on x86 Debian, as I just checked.